# Finding file directory and file name in C

Tags: c

I have a problem with showing file directory. I used `_splitpath` function to cut file direction and file name. Then, I used `strcat` to concatenate the drive name and directory. I also used this function for file name and it was Ok. I noticed that I can't concatenate directly to drive because the buffer size of driver is only 3. So, I concatenate drive to another character array and then concatenate with directory. Here comes the problem. When I put a breakpoint and debug, there's an exception after the _splitpath line. I don't know how to fix it so, please help me with my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char szPath[256] = {NULL};          
    char cDirCheck = '\\';                  
    char szDrive[_MAX_DRIVE] = {0};
    char szDir[_MAX_DIR] = {0};
    char szFileName[_MAX_FNAME] = {0};
    char szExt[_MAX_EXT] = {0};
    char pszPath[256] = {NULL};
    char* pszFname = NULL;

     if(cDirCheck != NULL) {
        _ splitpath(argv[0], szDrive, szDir, szFileName, szExt);
        strcat(pszPath, szDrive);
        strcat(pszPath, szDir);
        pszFname = strcat(szFileName, szExt);
        printf("\nUsage: %s fileName\n", pszFname);
        printf("EXE Path:%s", pszPath\n);
     } else {                       
        printf("\nUsage: %s fileName\n", argv[0]);
        printf("EXE Path : Current Folder\n");
    }
   return 0;
}
```

You may think file path and file name output correctly but the last printf of the else statement only show "EXE Path : ". I also don't know why it happened. Please give me some ideas. With regards...

Comment: BTW your program only compiles after some typos have been corrected. The test `cDirCheck != NULL` is always true so it is useless. But apart from that your program works fine here. You are writing about an exception after _splitpath. Tell us more about that.

Comment: When I used breakpoint and debugger as you said, "mov ecx,[esp+4]; ecx -> dest strin CXX0013: Error: missing operator" this error appeared. Please can you explain what is it about.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistakes. English is not my native language and I'm not very good at English.

Comment: Which operating system and which compiler/visual studio do you use ?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise and Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Comment: Very strange, try replacing `_splitpath` by `_splitpath_s` and look what happens. Here (VS2012, Windows 7) it works fine.

Comment: Is "EXE Path : Current Folder" also appear?

Comment: The output of if statement came correctly when I run this program. When I typed "C:\Users\Newbie\......\Debug\dircut.exe" in the command prompt without using cd, the result came out. But when I used cd, the else statement didn't work well. Final printf of half of the ouput is missing.

Comment: Try to put a `\n` here -> `printf("EXE Path:%s\n", pszPath);`. Edit your question and add what you type and which output you get.

Comment: In the command prompt, I typed "C:\Users\Newbie\.....\Debug\dircut.exe" without using '\>cd C:\Users\Newbie\......' In that case, if statement works. The output is correct. When I used '\> cd C:\Users\....', else statement works but the output is incorrect. It comes as 'In Usage dircut.exe filename\nEXE Path: '. In that case where's the "Current Folder" sentence gone? If I put if statement in comment out and run, the else statement works perfectly. No words missing. This is what I want to know.

Comment: I want to show you my output screenshot but I can't upload photo. Only 10 reputation can upload.

Comment: You don't need a screen shot you can copy the content of your command window with the right mouse button, but don't bother anymore, just read the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This is a stripped down version of your program that shows what is actually happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char szDrive[_MAX_DRIVE] = {0};
    char szDir[_MAX_DIR] = {0};
    char szFileName[_MAX_FNAME] = {0};
    char szExt[_MAX_EXT] = {0};

    _splitpath(argv[0], szDrive, szDir, szFileName, szExt);

    printf ("argv[0]    = %s\n\n", argv[0]) ;
    printf ("szDrive    = %s\n", szDrive) ;
    printf ("szDir      = %s\n", szDir) ;
    printf ("szFileName = %s\n", szFileName) ;
    printf ("szExt      = %s\n\n", szExt) ;

    return 0;
}
```

`argv[0]` is actually the name of the command you typed in the cmd window to invoke your program. So if you type `dircut`, `argv[0]` is `dircut`, if you type `dircut.exe`, `argv[0]` is `dircut.exe` and if you type `c:\xxx\dircut`, `argv[0]` is `c:\xxx\dircut` and so on.

Tests:

```
S:\>s:\dircut\debug\dircut.exe
argv[0]    = s:\dircut\debug\dircut.exe

szDrive    = s:
szDir      = \dircut\debug\
szFileName = dircut
szExt      = .exe


S:\>s:\dircut\debug\dircut
argv[0]    = s:\dircut\debug\dircut

szDrive    = s:
szDir      = \dircut\debug\
szFileName = dircut
szExt      =


S:\>cd dircut\debug

S:\dircut\Debug>dircut.exe
argv[0]    = dircut.exe

szDrive    =
szDir      =
szFileName = dircut
szExt      = .exe
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Micheal. Sorry about spending your times. I appreciate your answers.

Comment: That's what Stackoverflow is made for. Please accept the answer if it is what you wanted.